# JavaScript CSS parser

Tags: jquery, css, json, parsing

I'm searching a css parser for javascript that works like jquery, example:

```
var style = {

    '.test': {
        paddingTop: 20,
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        borderRadius: 5
    },

    '.test2': {
        color: '#888'
    }

}
```

this json must be convert in:

```
.test{
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}   
.test2 {
    color: #888;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: You seem to be looking for the inverse of a css parser, right ? Do you want the result to be a string ?

Comment: mmh, maybe I'm confusing...however yes, I want a string as result.

Comment: @thirtydot: Unserializing a JSON-based format to be injected as a `<style>` tag, for instance?

Comment: This doesn't seem useful to me because this is not the format in which your CSS should be. If you want to do "calculations" inside your CSS, use LESS or similar. Or, just return a raw string of CSS. How do you plan to handle units other than pixels? You'll need something more like `paddingTop: '20em'`, at which point you just have CSS in an awkward format.

Answer (score 2):

Something simple.

Replaces all `camelCase` to `css-hyphenation` (props to @AKX for better regex).

```
String.prototype.toCssProperty = function () {
    return this.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
};
```

Appends `px` to all numeric values.

```
if(typeof value === 'number')
    value += 'px';
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E54Cx/)

```
function addRule(selector, styles) {
    var builder = [];
    for(var key in styles) {
        if(styles.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            var value = styles[key];
            if(typeof value === 'number')
                value += 'px';

            builder.push(key.toCssProperty() + ':' + value);
        }
    }       

    var rule = builder.join('; ');
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule(selector,rule);
}

function applyStyles(s) {
    for(var key in s) {
        if(s.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            addRule(key, s[key]);            
        }
    }
};
```

If you just want the string, you should return that, instead of adding the css rule, as I'm doing in the demo.

I'm sure there are heaps of corner-cases that this doesn't cover. Implement with care.

Comment: `return this.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();`?

Comment: This not work with "opacity" case, infact IE wants an own declaration. The same for borderRadius...for this reason I was searching a plugin that behaves like jQuery.

Comment: @keepyourweb: Then add something like http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/ into the mix?